# how to get song cover art using TagLib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, taglib

Here's the code where I was able to get the song's picture/cover art.

```
TagLib::MPEG::File.open("song_file_name.mp3") do |file|
    tag = file.id3v2_tag

    cover = tag.frame_list('APIC').first
    mime_type = cover.mime_type
    picture = cover.picture
end
```

How can I convert the value of picture into a url or image's source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the content of the picture in a file, save it, and make it available on a web server.

Try to do something like:

```
TagLib::MPEG::File.open("song_file_name.mp3") do |file|
    tag = file.id3v2_tag

    cover = tag.frame_list('APIC').first
    mime_type = cover.mime_type
    picture = cover.picture

    extension = case cover.mime_type
      when 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg'
        'jpg'
      when 'image/gif'
        'gif'
      else
        raise "Mime not found"
    end

    file_name = "my_file.#{extension}"

    File.open(file_name, "w") do |f|
      f.write(picture)
    end

end
```